# Foriegn keys not edited in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using version of Ubuntu 13.10 and working in MySQL RDBMS using phpMyAdmin.

The table for-example `Foo` having only two foriegn keys `key1` and `key2`. The problem occurs, when I double click on cell of the table, it's not edited.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing to update or edit the cell of table in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I wonder if superuser is a better spot for this question?

Comment: What happens when you double click? Does the field change to an editable text box? Is there a unique or primary key defined on the table? (If not, the notice is displayed " Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." and editing by double-click doesn't work.)

Comment: Nothing happens, field not change to an editable text. There is no unique or primary key define in table, both are foreign keys. The option of Edit,Copy and delete features are not shown.